# WndProc Overloading + Unmanaged DLL Wrapper: Better way?

Tags: c#, dll, filter, unmanaged, wndproc

(BTW this is C# .NET 4.5)

I have some unmanaged DLL that talks to some hardware. I wrap a bunch of code and get something simple, as a class object, that I can create in a WinForm.

```
    private AvaSpec AS = new AvaSpec();

    public AvaSpec_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AS.SpectrumMeasuredEvent += (se, ev) => { SpectrumMeasured(ev); };

        AS.Init(this.Handle);
        AS.Activate();

        // configure as desired
        // AS.l_PrepareMeasData.m_IntegrationDelay = 0;

        if (AS.DeviceList.Count > 0)
        {
            AS.Start();
        }
    }
```

However, the DLL relies on receiving messages through WndProc. The best way I could figure out to do this is to overload the WndProc method on the Form:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // catch WndProc messages that AvaSpec defines as its own
        if (m.Msg == AvaSpec.WM_MEAS_READY || 
                m.Msg == AvaSpec.WM_APP || 
                m.Msg == AvaSpec.WM_DBG_INFOAs || 
                m.Msg == AvaSpec.WM_DEVICE_RESET )
        {
            AS.WndProcMessageReceived(ref m);
        }

        // else pass message on to default message handler
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

How can I hide this overload somehow in the class definition so that the overload method does not need to be added to the Form itself? There is some talk of the IMessageFilter interface, but it still looks to require some code in the form to add the filter. Any ideas on how to make this more elegant?

Comment: There is nothing to hide, it is just as visible and protected as the original Form.WndProc() that you overrode.

Comment: BTW I tried IMessageFilter interface, it works, until I move the form, and for some reason the messages stop flowing to the object...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out based on Colin Smith's hints.

You derive your class from NativeWindow:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx

Then assign the parent (form) Handle (that you pass by some initialization) to the Handle that NativeWindow provides to the class object. Then, you can overload the WndProc method directly in the object.

```
// object definition

public class AvaSpec : NativeWindow
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // catch WndProc messages that AvaSpec defines as its own
        if (m.Msg == AvaSpec.WM_MEAS_READY || 
            m.Msg == AvaSpec.WM_APP || 
            m.Msg == AvaSpec.WM_DBG_INFOAs || 
            m.Msg == AvaSpec.WM_DEVICE_RESET)
        {
            WndProcMessageReceived(ref m);
        }

        // Call base WndProc for default handling
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

...(snip)

```
    public void Init(IntPtr parentHandle)
    {
        this.AssignHandle(parentHandle);
```

...(snip)

and use it (pass handle pointer via some init) like so:

```
// WinForm definition

public partial class AvaSpec_X : Form
{
    private AvaSpec AS = new AvaSpec();

    public AvaSpec_X()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AS.SpectrumMeasuredEvent += (se, ev) => { SpectrumMeasured(ev); };

        AS.Init(this.Handle);
        AS.Activate();

        // configure as desired
        //AS.l_PrepareMeasData.m_IntegrationDelay = 0;

        if (AS.DeviceList.Count > 0)
        {
            AS.Start();
        }
    }
```

...(snip)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a hidden modeless "form"/window and then use its `.Handle` in the call to `'AS.Init'`.

By using a separate "window" rather than piggy-backing onto the main application window, it offers a bit better encapsulation.

For example, if in the future you needed to support the handling of multiple devices at the same time...then the "separate" windows would enable good separation of messages for different devices.

Your hardware/device handling code might use wParam or lParam to identify the "device id"...but it's more likely to be using them for something else, and relying on the "window destination" as the distinguisher.

Then let the main apps UI thread message pump...automatically dispatch messages to the windows you have created.

In your message handling code for that "window", you would handle messages, which would include the special privately registered messages such as WM_DBG_INFOAs, etc...which you then forward back to the `AvaSpec` via `WndProcMessageReceived`.

If that `AvaSpec` class is relying on you processing those messages in a timely fashion, then you might need to then explore creating multiple UI threads.

This might be needed if your main apps UI thread was getting overloaded, or was "busy" processing other messages e.g when resizing, moving window, etc.

By having a separate UI thread that is pumping the messages for your hidden "device" window, then it might provide a better response for your "device".

Note: multiple UI threads is an advanced topic, and there are some gotchas, but basically it involves creating a thread, telling it to use the STA (single-threaded apartment), creating your window form, and then usually use `Application.Run` with that form to cause message pumping.